# Using an ES module in the browser

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm looking to understand more about how to build and use an ES Module in the browser (I am developing this locally in a node environment).

Let's say I have this piece of code

*index.js*

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const BASE_URL = 'localhost:9000';
const myLocalStorage = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? mockLocalStorage : window.localStorage;

export async function getDeviceId() {
  const API_URL = `${BASE_URL}/get_device_id`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(API_URL);
    const uuid = await response.json();

    if (uuid && uuid.length > 0) {
      console.log(uuid)
    } else {
      throw new Error('UUID is not available');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching uuid:', error);
  }
}
```

At this point I have 2 requirements, have the code be consumed as a module in a browser and also make it backwards compatible for ES5 and consumed via `require` (I believe this is where webpack comes into it)

*As a module*

If I want to load this in the browser i have seen that we use this syntax

```
<script type="module">
  import { getDeviceId } from '/src/index.js';
</script>
```

Do I still need to use webpack to bundle this up as an ES module? If I serve it as it is, I get an error with `dotenv`:

> TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "dotenv". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: _" ...  and also make it backwards compatible for ES5 ... "_ that's typically where [babel](https://babeljs.io/) comes into play.

Comment: webpack can and will (not entirely sure about the newest/newer versions ; it's been a while) transpile and bundle ES modules to commonJS code automatically.

Comment: _" ...  how to build and use an ES Module in the browser  ... "_ modern browsers actually are capable of using ES modules directly without the need of transpiling. However, using node specific packages (like `node-fetch`) needs actually more work than just importing the module in a browser context.

Comment: The problem with your current code is that it is _node-specific_ and not agnostic. `dotenv` is a module that loads `.env` files and puts them in `process.env` - neither of those are available in a browser.

Comment: What webpack usually does is inline package `require`s or `import`s. However, if those packages are not written in pure JavaScript (i.e., are dependent on some concept that isn't in JavaScript's spec) then this doesn't help you.

Comment: For a browser compatible version `node-fetch` and `dotenv` would need to get replaced, I don't know if webpack is capable of doing this automatically, or if you need to configure it or if it's possible at all. I'd assume it's possible since fetch and node-fetch are _very_ popular.

Comment: @Marco Thanks, this helps and I can see where I’ve gone wrong already. Any recommendations for handling .env so that my implementation is agnostic ?

Comment: That's a _good_ question, some modules/functions are able to be polyfilled by webpack and co., meaning your code doesn't have to be **strictly** agnostic but IMO I consider that a bit sloppy and more of a "quick fix" or workaround. If you're building something from the ground up, I'd separate the different concerns just like you would with (let's say) a database. In your case that means _only_ reading `.env` files in a node context and in the browser something else. Of course, you would decouple that from the rest of your logic to easily adapt to a different environment (browser, node etc.).

Comment: _" ... some modules/functions are able to be polyfilled by webpack and co. ..."_ If I recall correctly, webpack for example is capable of "emulating" the global `process` variable from node without much work.

Comment: I'd assume you're using `dotenv` (or `.env`) to configure some aspect of your application - that's something you can easily decouple by passing a configuration object to your application's entry point (or logic) - the consuming function doesn't not need to know or care where the configuration came from.

Comment: @Marco Any examples you could point to where i could do the above please? Thank you for your comments, have proven very useful

Comment: It's been a while, do you still need help for this? If so, what do you mean by "examples like above" can you be a bit more specific?